# Monitor disk utilization on ec2 instance through cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am fetching disk metrics from cloud watch. For this I have deployed CW agent on my EC2 instance.   But no sure how to get metrics for multple disk partition (C drive & D drive) on a single instance. Can anybody help over this?

steps to fetch metrics for multiple disk partition.

Comment: You need to configure the cloudwatch agent config file https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS can't 'see' into your instance to ask the Operating System about free disk space. The same goes for Free Memory, since that is managed by the Operating System 'inside' the instance.

Instead, you can [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html):

> Collect internal system-level metrics from Amazon EC2 instances across operating systems. The metrics can include in-guest metrics, in addition to the metrics for EC2 instances.

After installing the agent, you need to [Create the CloudWatch agent configuration file - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file.html) that tells the agent which metrics to send to AWS.

It appears that, for Windows instances, the metric includes a disk identifier, such as `LogicalDisk % Free Space` -- however, the documentation isn't perfectly clear so please experiment with it.